# How to format a page using a command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, format, string-formatting

What im going to ask isnt a big deal, i want to know if i can format an html page before the server sends it to the client. here is an example, this is the source code of an aspx page:

```
    <tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=4'>שאלות על HTML</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>בפורום הזה תוכלו לשאול שאלות על HTML</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr><tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=5'>שאלות על C#</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>בפורום הזה תוכלו לשאול שאלות על C#</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr><tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=6'>שאלות על ASPX</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>בפורום הזה תוכלו לשאול שאלות על ASPX</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr><tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=7'>דיבורים</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>פורום דיבורים</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr><tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=9'>פורום אדמין</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>לאדמינים בלבד</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>2</td><td>Admin</td></tr>
```

(Ignore the hebrew text), thats how it shows it, but i want it to look that way:

```
   <tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=4'>שאלות על HTML</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>בפורום הזה תוכלו לשאול שאלות על HTML</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr>
    <tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=5'>שאלות על C#</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>בפורום הזה תוכלו לשאול שאלות על C#</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr>
    <tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=6'>שאלות על ASPX</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>בפורום הזה תוכלו לשאול שאלות על ASPX</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr>
    <tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=7'>דיבורים</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>פורום דיבורים</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>1</td><td>All</td></tr>
    <tr id='td'><td><table align='right'><tr><td align='right' valign='top'><a class='Link' href='TheardList.aspx?f=9'>פורום אדמין</a></td></tr><tr><td style='font-size:small;' align='right' valign='middle'>לאדמינים בלבד</td></tr></table></td><td align='right'>2</td><td>Admin</td></tr>
```

Its just a  matter of aesthetics and nothing seruios, it looks exactly the same in the browser. is there any kind of command or something that i can put at the end of the document that will format the page before sending it to the client?
(im using C# and asp.net) Thank you! :)

Comment: why not format the source code? visual studio can help you automatically format documents.

Comment: Because its generating the html code while the page loads so i cant format it.

Comment: Are you using MVC or ASP Pages?

Comment: can you try this? var formattedOutput = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(myHtmlString).ToString();

Comment: i dont think that this command would help, if it works it will just put all the html page into a var and then you do nothing with it.

Comment: is this a dynamically created html or you have an unformatted html page?

Comment: @Sushil It is a dynamically created html page

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the aesthetics on the server side too i.e. Edit > Advanced > Format Document

If you are generating this code dynamically, you could look to use the HtmlTextWriter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Its generating the html code while the page runs and returns a string that is being displayed on the client side, the string looks all messy because the C# dosent care about it being messy

Comment: @ShakedDahan You mean this HTML is generated dynamically?

Comment: @ShakedDahan Use an HtmlTextWriter